# How to use Delegate to control QTableView's rows height

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qtableview

This code creates a single `QTableView` with `QSpinBoxes` set as its delegated items. I want to use `SpinBoxDelegate`'s `sizeHint()` method to return a fixed `QSize(64,64)` according to a technique described here:
[Adjusting the height of a QTableView Row](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8738)

Unfortunately the specified `QSize(64,64)` is only returned for a single row # 1 (?). Why does it not happen for every row? Where is the error in a code?

[image]

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class SpinBoxDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QSpinBox(parent)
        editor.setMinimum(0)
        editor.setMaximum(100)

        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, spinBox, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)

        spinBox.setValue(value)

    def setModelData(self, spinBox, model, index):
        spinBox.interpretText()
        value = spinBox.value()

        model.setData(index, value, Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        print option
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        print 'sizeHint', index.row(), index.column()
        return QSize(64,64)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QStandardItemModel(4, 2)
    tableView = QTableView()
    tableView.setModel(model)

    delegate = SpinBoxDelegate()
    tableView.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    for row in range(4):
        for column in range(2):
            index = model.index(row, column, QModelIndex())
            model.setData(index, (row + 1) * (column + 1))

    tableView.resizeRowToContents(True)

    tableView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was to use `tableView.resizeRowToContents(True)` instead of `tableView.resizeRowsToContents()` which updates all the currently visible QModelIndexes. Fixed code is below:

[image]

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class SpinBoxDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QSpinBox(parent)
        editor.setMinimum(0)
        editor.setMaximum(100)

        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, spinBox, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)

        spinBox.setValue(value)

    def setModelData(self, spinBox, model, index):
        spinBox.interpretText()
        value = spinBox.value()

        model.setData(index, value, Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        print option
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        print 'sizeHint', index.row(), index.column()
        return QSize(64,64)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QStandardItemModel(4, 2)
    tableView = QTableView()
    tableView.setModel(model)

    delegate = SpinBoxDelegate()
    tableView.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    for row in range(4):
        for column in range(2):
            index = model.index(row, column, QModelIndex())
            model.setData(index, (row + 1) * (column + 1))

    tableView.resizeRowsToContents()

    tableView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Or here is the skeleton version of the same concept:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class ForSizeOnlyDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        print 'sizeHint', index.row(), index.column()
        return QSize(64,64)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QStandardItemModel(14, 12)
    tableView = QTableView()
    tableView.setModel(model)

    delegate = ForSizeOnlyDelegate()

    tableView.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    tableView.resizeRowsToContents()

    tableView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```